# How do I fix my 32/64 bit problem encountered when executing a certain line of code in a .NET project?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, 32bit-64bit, dllimport, lib

I am working in Visual Studio 17 building a .NET project
I'm running into trouble every time I try to call a function from the dll file. I'm using a combination of using 
    `DllImport("PXCP.dll", EntryPoint:="XCP_InitializeCanChannel")>`
and using the correct namespaces within the .VB files. After searching at lengths on here and elsewhere, I've determined it has to do with a x86/x64 bit conflict. I've tried remedying the problem with the following solutions:

- copying/pasting them directly into the debug/release bin folders and executable directory
- adding the .dll (32bit & 64bit) in their respective folders (SysWOW64/System32)
- Added multiple paths in Project>Properties>References that contain the dll

I keep on getting an exception thrown when it reaches a function from the dll in question. "System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'Name.dll': The specified module could not be found.'"

Occasionally, when I'm playing around with the build settings, I get the exception "System.BadImageFormatException: 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'"

Is there something I could be missing, or something I can do to try and get past the exception? I would also like to know if I might have to move/import the .lib file that goes along with the .dll.

Thanks

Comment: You certainly should not be adding DLLs into the system folders. Place them in the same directory as the executable. Quite possibly the problem is that you are missing a dependency. For instance the MSVC runtime. Without knowledge of the precise steps you have taken it's hard to say much.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks for the input! I've updated the question to include that the dll file is in the executable directory and to clarify how I am calling the dll in the project. 
I'm checking out my dependencies to see if that's the case.
What other information do you believe will be useful to help diagnose this problem?

Comment: If the right DLL really is in the executable directory, and all the dependencies are present, then you won't see that error. Ergo, there are missing DLLs in the executable directory, or missing dependencies. Of course, now that you have sprayed the DLLs all over the system, it could be a little hard to know what's wrong. You really should undo everything you did in those bullet points and just put the DLLs in the executable directory.

Comment: Not sure why you aren't heeding my comment above. Stop guessing. Lib files are not relevant here. It's as I state above. It's that simple.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just finished deleting the .dll files off all the directories they were in. I currently only have it on the executable directory **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE**.  I am still getting the same exception handle thrown.

Comment: So you either the dll name is wrong in the code, or you are missing a dependency. No the explanation for that error.